# org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node: main ()V:

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm

i am learning kotlin.

in the following code if give *double* value to `ANOTHER_CONSTANT` then i get this error.
for other types it works just fine.
what could be the reason.

```
const val ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 833.1 // not compiling
// const val ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 833.1f // float works, and other types also work

fun main() {
    println("ANOTHER_CONSTANT ${ANOTHER_CONSTANT} :: ${ANOTHER_CONSTANT::class}")
}
```

error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
main ()V:
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    NOP
    GETSTATIC java/lang/Double.TYPE : Ljava/lang/Class;
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lkotlin/reflect/KClass;
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.stringPlus (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 0
    NOP
   L1
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 1
   L2
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L3
    NOP
    GOTO L4
   L4
    LINENUMBER 8 L4
    RETURN
   L5
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 2

File is unknown
The root cause org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(MethodVisitor.java:782)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:772)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethod(ClassCodegen.kt:405)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:133)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLowerKt$codegenPhase$1$1.lower(JvmLower.kt:304)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:191)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:618)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 5: Cannot pop operand off an empty stack.
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.boxing.PopBackwardPropagationTransformer$Transformer.transform(PopBackwardPropagationTransformer.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.boxing.PopBackwardPropagationTransformer.transform(PopBackwardPropagationTransformer.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.CompositeMethodTransformer.transform(CompositeMethodTransformer.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.OptimizationMethodVisitor.performTransformations(OptimizationMethodVisitor.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:70)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Cannot pop operand off an empty stack.
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.pop(Frame.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.executeInvokeInsn(Frame.java:640)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.execute(Frame.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:187)
    ... 57 more
```

It's gradle kotlin console app project, if i need to install any extra dependency pls suggest how.

Comment: Failed to reproduce with latest stable Kotlin version 1.5.20 (or even 1.4.32). Try to update your Kotlin compiler / IDE plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my kotlin plug in version
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin
from 1.4.10 to 1.5.21